# How could I display a certain number of input fields based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox, user-input

I am trying to make a calculator that displays a certain number of input text fields based on a number entered earlier (variable). For example:

> How many **whatever**? (text field that inputs to a variable)

How should I make the page (`onBlur`) generate a number of text fields based on the user's number?

Comment: Is jQuery allowed? Is posible with or with out. But with jQuery its shorter (not faster :) )

Comment: jQuery is allowed, yes. Glad you asked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function addInputs(elm) {
  var result = document.querySelector('#result');
  result.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(elm.value); i++) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="textfield ' + i + '" />';
    result.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-top:5px;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="addInputs(this)" placeholder="Type a numder" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Version of Mosh Feu's Version

Javascript Part:

```
function addInputs(elm) {
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < parseInt($(elm).val()); i++) {
    html += '<input type="text" placeholder="Textfield '+i+'">';
  }
  $('#result').html(html);
}
```

HTML Part:

```
<input type="text" onblur="addInputs(this)" placeholder="Type a numder" />
<div id="result"></div>
```